# how to compare values from 2 queries and get final result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query which gives the results of the oracle/grid home and its install time:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        HOME_LOCATION, INSTALL_TIME, home_name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY HOME_LOCATION order by INSTALL_TIME desc) AS RN
    FROM
        sysman_ro.mgmt$oh_patch
    WHERE
        host_name LIKE 'host970%'
)
SELECT 
    HOME_LOCATION, INSTALL_TIME 
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1 
  AND home_location NOT LIKE '%agent%'
  AND NOT (home_location LIKE '%agent%' OR home_location LIKE '%ggs%' OR
         home_location LIKE '%Middleware%' OR home_location LIKE '%19.%' )
  AND home_location IN (SELECT DISTINCT MC.VALUE 
                        FROM METRIC_CURRENT MC
                        WHERE METRIC_NAME = 'ME$ORATAB'
                          AND mc.target_name LIKE 'host970%')
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77eMP.png)

Now I have another similar query to get the oracle/grid home **not** in use and their install time:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        HOME_LOCATION, INSTALL_TIME, home_name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY HOME_LOCATION order by INSTALL_TIME desc) AS RN
    FROM
        sysman_ro.mgmt$oh_patch
    WHERE
        host_name LIKE 'host970%'
)
SELECT 
    HOME_LOCATION, INSTALL_TIME 
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1 
  AND home_location NOT LIKE '%agent%'
  AND NOT (home_location LIKE '%agent%' OR home_location LIKE '%ggs%' OR home_location LIKE '%Middleware%' OR home_location LIKE '%19.%' )
  AND home_location NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT MC.VALUE 
                            FROM METRIC_CURRENT MC
                            WHERE METRIC_NAME = 'ME$ORATAB'
                              AND mc.target_name LIKE 'host970%')
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcLho.png)

I am trying to get the results of homes where the install time of non-used home from 2nd query is less than 30 days of the install time of the used home from 1st query.

We need to compare similar homes like db_1 with db_1 etc.

I tried some thing like below, but didn't succeed.

```
select a.*, b.*.....
```

Can you please help with a suitable way forward.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, "similar homes" can be tricky. Depends on how you define "similar".

Is a lemon similar to banana?

- No, of course not!
- Yes, they are both yellow.

As I said, it *depends*.

While you're making up your mind, see whether `UTL_MATCH` package helps. Sample data in lines #1 - 16 (`a` and `b` CTEs representing your current queries).

```
SQL> with
  2  a (home_location, install_time) as
  3    (select '/local/dbms/oracle/product/11.2.0.4.201020/db_1' , date '2020-11-06' from dual union all
  4     select '/local/dbms/oracle/product/11.2.0.4.201020/db_2' , date '2020-11-06' from dual union all
  5     select '/local/dbms/oracle/product/11.2.0.4.201020/db_5' , date '2021-01-13' from dual union all
  6     select '/local/grid/oragrid/product/11.2.0.4.201020/grid', date '2020-11-06' from dual
  7    ),
  8  b (home_location, install_time) as
  9    (select 'local/dbms/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/db_1'        , date '2017-02-15' from dual union all
 10     select 'local/dbms/oracle/product/11.2.0.4.200714/db_2' , date '2020-08-13' from dual union all
 11     select 'local/grid/oragrid/product/11.2.0.4.200714/grid', date '2020-08-13' from dual union all
 12     select 'local/grid/oragrid/product/11.2.0.3/grid'       , date '2017-02-15' from dual union all
 13     select 'local/dbms/oracle/product/11.2.0.4.200714/db_1' , date '2020-08-13' from dual union all
 14     select 'local/dbms/oracle/product/11.2.0.3/db_5'        , date '2017-02-15' from dual union all
 15     select 'local/dbms/oracle/product/11.2.0.4.200714/db_5' , date '2020-10-02' from dual
 16    )
 17  select distinct a.home_location,
 18         b.home_location,
 19         a.install_time,
 20         b.install_time,
 21         --
 22         utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(a.home_location, b.home_location) match,
 23         abs(b.install_time - a.install_time) diff
 24  from a join b on utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(a.home_location, b.home_location) > 80
 25    and abs(a.install_time - b.install_time) <= 50;

HOME_LOCATION                                    HOME_LOCATION                                   INSTALL_T INSTALL_T  MATCH  DIFF
------------------------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------- --------- --------- ------ -----
/local/dbms/oracle/product/11.2.0.4.201020/db_1  local/dbms/oracle/product/11.2.0.4.200714/db_5  06-nov-20 02-oct-20     81    35
/local/dbms/oracle/product/11.2.0.4.201020/db_2  local/dbms/oracle/product/11.2.0.4.200714/db_5  06-nov-20 02-oct-20     81    35

SQL>
```

You'd modify conditions in the `WHERE` clause so that the result fits your needs.

---

Or, if you wanted to compare only the last part of the `HOME_LOCATION`, you could

```
 <snip>
 17  select distinct a.home_location,
 18         b.home_location,
 19         a.install_time,
 20         b.install_time,
 21         abs(b.install_time - a.install_time) diff
 22  from a join b on regexp_substr(a.home_location, '\w+$') = regexp_substr(b.home_location, '\w+$')
 23  where abs(b.install_time - a.install_time) < 100;

HOME_LOCATION                                    HOME_LOCATION                                   INSTALL_T INSTALL_T  DIFF
------------------------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------- --------- --------- -----
/local/grid/oragrid/product/11.2.0.4.201020/grid local/grid/oragrid/product/11.2.0.4.200714/grid 06-nov-20 13-aug-20    85
/local/dbms/oracle/product/11.2.0.4.201020/db_1  local/dbms/oracle/product/11.2.0.4.200714/db_1  06-nov-20 13-aug-20    85
/local/dbms/oracle/product/11.2.0.4.201020/db_2  local/dbms/oracle/product/11.2.0.4.200714/db_2  06-nov-20 13-aug-20    85

SQL>
```

Comment: how can we change the regexp condition to match only the last 2 characters in home_location?

Comment: You don't need regular expression for that; use a simple `substr(home_location, -2)`

Answer (score 0):

The code is well, and I like your structure.
I can suggest you optimize the query.
The IN statement makes a query slower, and DISTINCT more.
The solution is EXISTS statement, which checks only 1 time.

To combine both queries, first, we need to optimize these aspects.
Also, I understand INSTALL_TIME as the Date format and parameter which you compare.
Is not clear which one is your PK, I choose HOME_LOCATION.
The final WHERE statement, if is not date, you must convert to date.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        HOME_LOCATION, INSTALL_TIME, home_name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY HOME_LOCATION order by INSTALL_TIME desc) AS RN
    FROM
        sysman_ro.mgmt$oh_patch
    WHERE
        host_name LIKE 'host970%'
)
SELECT a.HOME_LOCATION, b.HOME_LOCATION, a.INSTALL_TIME, b.INSTALL_TIME 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        HOME_LOCATION, INSTALL_TIME 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RN = 1 
        AND home_location NOT LIKE '%agent%'
        AND NOT (
             home_location LIKE '%agent%' OR home_location LIKE '%ggs%' OR
             home_location LIKE '%Middleware%' OR home_location LIKE '%19.%'
        )
        AND EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM METRIC_CURRENT mc 
        WHERE METRIC_NAME = 'ME$ORATAB' AND 
            mc.TARGET_NAME LIKE 'host970%' AND
            cte.HOME_LOCATION = mc.VALUE
        )
) a JOIN (
    SELECT 
        HOME_LOCATION, INSTALL_TIME 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RN = 1 
    AND home_location NOT LIKE '%agent%'
    AND NOT (
         home_location LIKE '%agent%' OR home_location LIKE '%ggs%' OR
         home_location LIKE '%Middleware%' OR home_location LIKE '%19.%'
    )
    AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM METRIC_CURRENT mc 
    WHERE METRIC_NAME = 'ME$ORATAB' AND 
        mc.TARGET_NAME LIKE 'host970%' AND
        cte.HOME_LOCATION = mc.VALUE
) b ON (a.HOME_LOCATION = b.HOME_LOCATION)
WHERE ABS(a.INSTALL_TIME - b.INSTALL_TIME) <= 30;
```